# what site should I ask redirect questions?

Tags: discussion

I have a site I'm changing the domain and have questions regarding redirects.  the site is wordpress but much of the redirect could be considered outside of wordpress.  Where should I ask the question so as not to violate rules?

Comment: honestly the only answer I can see for this is "it depends", you'd need to share technical details as the subject of redirects is too broad for this question. Some questions will be on topic, others will need to be asked elsewhere, but where that would be depends on the question!

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/